# Atualizar uma (TextView) através de uma outra função

Tags: android

Estou tentando atualizar o texto de uma TextView através de uma função, mas eu estou Obtendo um erro logo depois da linha **Log.i("ATUALIZAR","-1-");** *(linha 12)* O código deveria funcionar perfeitamente quando eu chamasse a função **atualizar()** mas por algum motivo da erro.

```
public void atualizar(){
        Log.i("ATUALIZAR","-0-"+Usuario.retorneINFO());
        if(Usuario.retorneINFO() != null){
            JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(Usuario.retorneINFO()).nextValue();
            String chat = object.getString("1");

            chat = chat.replaceAll("!hx01", " "); // troca todos os !hx01 por um espaço em branco
            chat = chat.replaceAll("!hx02", "'");
            chat = chat.replaceAll("!hx03", "\"");

            Log.i("ATUALIZAR","-1-");
            TextView msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
            msg.setText(chat);  
            Log.i("ATUALIZAR","-2-");
            new Connect().execute("http://animesslife.engine001.com/chat/get_chat.php");
            Log.i("ATUALIZAR","-3-");

        }

    }
```

Resumindo Eu preciso atualizar o texto dessa **TextView** *msg.setText(chat)* chamando a mesma através de uma função

- Eu tentei Colocar (View v) como parâmetro da função atualizar() mas não deu certo

É possível fazer isso ou dentro de uma função chamada pelo .xml?
Obrigado

EDIT : Esse é meu xml

> ```
> <Button
>     android:id="@+id/Enviar"
>     style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>     android:onClick="Send"
>     android:text="Enviar" />
>
> <EditText
>     android:id="@+id/AreaDeTexto"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Enviar"
>     android:inputType="text" >
>
>     <requestFocus />
> </EditText>
>
> <ScrollView
>
>     android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_above="@+id/Enviar"
>     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:orientation="vertical" >
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/message"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
>     </LinearLayout>
> </ScrollView>
> ```

Comment: Verifica se o nome do id do TextView é message... faz um Log de TextView msg, compartilhar ai tbm o layout onde está o TextView... isso vai ajudar muito a encontrar a solução. *Faz o debug e vai indo de ponto em ponto pra ver, sempre poste o msg do logcat que ai é batata.

Comment: O nome é message sim, Eu copiei o código de outra parte que tava funcionando legal... não tenho menor ideia do porque desse erro :(, Pronto coloquei o xml do layout

Comment: Vai em Window -> ShowView -> Other -> LogCat. Essa janela vai te mostrar onde esta o erro da sua aplicação, assim que vc executa-la. Cola ai pra gente tbm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mesmo sendo poucas informações, acredito, pelo que eu deduzo ali, você está chamando um UI dentro de uma Thread e ela não consegue se conectar diretamente em sua interface, por isso da o erro. Faz o seguinte, executa outra thread para conectar a interface:

```
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            TextView msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
            msg.setText(chat);
        }
    });
```

Essa tipo de Thread é responsável por fazer esse tipo de conexão. Ela faz parte da `Activity` caso a forma acima não esteja disponível tente: `getActivity().runOnUiThread...`